# Symfony: templating, check if base.html.php is already extended

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, templating

I have a small problem.

Im creating currently a Menu which works on ajax calls and should only replace a specific path part.

My `base.html.php` is this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <?php if ($view['slots']->has('sidebar')): ?>
          <?php $view['slots']->output('sidebar') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <?php $view['slots']->output('content') ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My pages are all build like this:

```
<?php $view->extend('Bundle::base.html.php') ?>
<?php $view['slots']->start('sidebar') ?>
<ul>
</ul>
<?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>
<?php $view['slots']->start('content') ?>
  some content
<?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>
```

My problem is now when im loading a new page via ajax call and replace the `contentWrapper`, it puts also once again the whole `base.html.php` into my `contentWrapper`.
The problem is, im using the current way because it should be also possible to access the files with the whole `base.html.php` with a single URL, without clicking first.

Is there a way to check if `base.html.php` had been already expanded?
Or is there another solution which could solve my case easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if it is an ajax request in your controller and then conditionnally extend or not to the `base.html.php` template :

Controller :

```
public function someAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // ...
    return $this->render(
        'MyBundle:Controller:action.html.php', 
        array('isAjax' => $request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    );
}
```

Template :

```
<?php 
if ($isAjax) { 
    $view->extend('Bundle::base.html.php');
}
// ...
?>
```

Or you could also check directly in the template :

```
<?php 
if ($app->request->xmlHttpRequest) { 
    $view->extend('Bundle::base.html.php');
}
// ...
?>
```

Or at last, you could get only the html content you want from the response (not the cleanest way to go since you retreive useless content). Assuming you use `jQuery` for your ajax request :

```
$.get('/url', function(html){
    $('#contentWrapper').html($(html).find('#contentWrapper').html());
});
// or 
$('#contentWrapper').load('/url #contentWrapper');
```